# How can I filter JSON data as per specific value in React using filter?

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, filter

I have JSON data:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"sany","email":"san@yahoo.com","pass":"sany","groups":
{"id":1,"name":"Admin"}},{"id":2,"name":"jiwan","email":"jiwan@yahoo.com",
  "pass":"john ","groups":{"id":2,"name":"Student"}}]
```

I can list out all the JSON values using map in React, but not sure how to filter, with specific email.

```
return(<div>
{jsonData.filter( user=> user.email==="san@yahoo.com")} //not working, giving issue

            {jsonData.map((user)=>
            {
                return <h1>{
                    user.email
                }</h1>
            }
            )}

        </div>)
```

Getting error:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name, email, pass, groups}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `Array.filter` returns new array and you need to `map` the filtered `array` not to original.

```
return (
  <div>
    {jsonData.filter(user=> user.email === "san@yahoo.com").map((user)=> {
        return <h1>{user.email}</h1>
      }
    )}
  </div>
)
```

or you can save the filtered.

```
render() {

  const filteredArray = jsonData.filter(user=> user.email === "san@yahoo.com");

  return (
    <div>
      {filteredArray.map((user)=> {
          return <h1>{user.email}</h1>
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Array.prototype.filter create new array. So you can chain filter and map. For example. `jsonData.filter(({email})=> email==="san@yahoo.com").map(({email})=> <h1>{email}</h1>);`.